# Nikon D750 Autofocus Vastly Inferior to Canon DSLR Autofocus: Rented D5 and 850 - Autofocus Beautiful

Tags: autofocus

I own a Nikon D 750 and prior to that a D7000. The autofocus is vastly inferior to any Canon full frame camera. I rented a Nikon D5 and the autofocus was wonderful. I heard they put the D5 autofocus system in the 850, so I rented it and it was superb. I'm told that all Nikon post 850 cameras now have the D5 autofocus system. So, I want a 2nd camera not two new cameras, so I need to get the D5 autofocus system  installed in my 750. How does that happen?

Comment: "get the D5 autofocus system installed in my 750. How does that happen?" - It doesn't? Buy two second hand D850's? That's what I would do if i wanted a 2 identical camera setup and sell what i don't need.

Comment: Maybe you should switch to Canon :)

Comment: "How does that happen?" – For most people, it doesn't.  You'd need to reverse engineer both the D750 and D850 so that you can reprogram the D750 using compatible portions of the D850 firmware.

Answer (score 3):

> How does that happen?

It doesn't.

At least it wouldn't without Nikon releasing a massive firmware update that would be totally out of character for Nikon to do. And that's even assuming there are no hardware limitations of the D750 AF system compared to the D850 AF system hardware.

<sub>I'd also respectfully disagree with the assertion that the AF system of the Nikon D750 is inferior to any Canon FF camera. The EOS 5D Mark II was fairly notorious for having true professional grade image quality combined with a woefully underwhelming consumer grade AF system. It refused to AF at all in anything approaching low light. Even in good light it was as inconsistent from shot-to-shot in burst mode as the Rebels at that time were, and more inconsistent by far than the contemporary 1D and 1Ds models. I shot almost 100,000 frames with my 5D mark II, so I'm very aware of its limitations compared to the 5D Mark III and IV, which had much improved AF systems compared to the 5D and 5D Mark II, though they were still not as good as the 1D X and 1D X Mark II AF systems upon which they were based.</sub>